# Programming language for 'dynamic' search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, dynamic

I am a complete beginner, so please excuse if this question is maybe phrased incorrectly or I am using the wrong terms for certain things.

I have got an MS Word Document in which there are, say, four-hundred diary entries. The software I want to write enables the user to search for specific terms within one entry. So I might want to have all the diary entries that contain both the words "happy" and "sad". Another option I want to include is to search for all diary entries written between e.g. 2008 and 2012 etc.

I would like the search to be 'dynamic', in the sense that the user might type in one word, and while that word is being typed the results-table already filters all the diary entries. So the table changes while the user is typing the word, according to what is currently being typed in the search box.

Is this possible & what exactly is this feature called? What programming language would you recommend me? I would like to have all of this online, so maybe php or ruby would be useful?

Comment: Sounds like you need to parse the files (any language you like), store in something you can index and implement full-text search (SQL database and elasticsearch), and use autocomplete for the client search (JavaScript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice of Ruby-on-Rails is apt for this issue:

> 1. Store each diary entry as a database entry
> 2. Search these entries using "full text search" - either on the db, or third party
> 3. Return the "live" functionality with JS

---

**MVC**

Rails uses [`MVC` programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to give you ability to save into the database. This is important because if you're going to develop in rails, you'll need to keep to the MVC pattern:

[image]

Basically, you keep your Diary entries in the `database`, use the `controller` to manipulate the data & use the `view` to show the data:

```
#app/models/entry.rb
Class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
   #-> stores & brings back the entry data
end

#app/controllers/entries_controller.rb
Class EntriesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :js, :html, :json, only: :search
    def index
       @entries = Entry.all
    end

    def search
       @entries = Entry.search params[:query]
       respond_with @entries
    end
end


#config/routes.rb
resources :entries do
   collection do
       match :search, via [:get, :post]
   end
end
```

--

**Full Text Search**

When you send the request to your controller, the way you'll handle the search will be with a [class method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) in your Entry model (that's where you get your data from), either referencing -

```
#app/models/entry.rb
Class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.search(query)
       where("title LIKE '%#{query}%'")
    end
end
```

You can either use [full text search for the SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) variant you're using, or use a third party search, like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or something

--

**"Live" Search**

You can get "live" search working with Javascript (example [here](http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk)):

[image]

There are a [number of tutorials](http://aymeric.gaurat.net/2010/how-to-develop-live-search-textbox-in-ruby-on-rails/) on how to do this online - just Google `live search rails` or `autocomplete rails`. However, the principle is basically the same for all implementations:

> - JS will capture the text entered into a search box
> - JS sends Ajax request to your Rails controller
> - Controller sends response to ajax
> - JS takes response & shows on screen

Notice how this is primarily focused on the **JS** element? Here's the code we use:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//Livesearch
    $(document).ready( function() {

        var base_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

        $('#SearchSearch').searchbox({
            url: base_url + '/search/',
            param: 'search',
            dom_id: '#livesearch',
            loading_css: '#livesearch_loading'
        })      

    });

#app/assets/javascripts/livesearch.js
// Author: Ryan Heath
// http://rpheath.com

(function($) {
  $.searchbox = {}

  $.extend(true, $.searchbox, {
    settings: {
        url: 'search',
        param: 'search',
        dom_id: '#livesearch',
        minChars: 2,
        loading_css: '#livesearch_loading',
        del_id: '#livesearch_del'
    },

    loading: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.loading_css).show()
    },

    idle: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.loading_css).hide()
    },

    start: function() {
      $.searchbox.loading()
      $(document).trigger('before.searchbox')
    },

    stop: function() {
      $.searchbox.idle()
      $(document).trigger('after.searchbox')
    },

    kill: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).fadeOut(50)
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).html('')
        $($.searchbox.settings.del_id).fadeOut(100)
    },

    reset: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).html('')
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).fadeOut(50)
        $('#SearchSearch').val('')
        $($.searchbox.settings.del_id).fadeOut(100)
    },

    process: function(terms) {

        if(/\S/.test(terms)) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url:  $.searchbox.settings.url,
                    data: {search: terms.trim()},
                    complete: function(data) {  
                        $($.searchbox.settings.del_id).fadeIn(50)
                        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).html(data.responseText)

                        if (!$($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).is(':empty')) {
                            $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).fadeIn(100)
                        }

                        $.searchbox.stop();
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }else{
            $.searchbox.kill();
        }
    }
  });



    $.fn.searchbox = function(config) {
        var settings = $.extend(true, $.searchbox.settings, config || {})

        $(document).trigger('init.searchbox')
        $.searchbox.idle()

        return this.each(function() {
            var $input = $(this)

            $input
            .keyup(function() { 
                if ($input.val() != this.previousValue) {

                    if(/\S/.test($input.val().trim()) &&  $input.val().trim().length > $.searchbox.settings.minChars){ 
                        $.searchbox.start()
                        $.searchbox.process($input.val())
                    }else{
                        $.searchbox.kill()
                    }

                    this.previousValue = $input.val()

                }
            })
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
```